# Different fontsize for minted and mintinline

Tags: fontsize, minted, java

I was wondering if it is possible to distinguish between `\mintinline` and `\begin{minted}`, to use different font size for both.

Background: I'm placing java code in my document with `\begin{minted}` and I set the font-size globally with `\setminted[java]{fontsize=\footnotesize}`. But when I want to show some code parts inline, I need to have a larger font size (for aesthetic reasons :) ) so I have to use `\mintinline[fontsize=\small]{java}` everytime.
Maybe it is possible to copy the java settings and create something like `\mintinline{javainline}`, but I did not find information on this.

 
As requested a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[java]{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
This is inline code: \mintinline[fontsize=\normalsize]{java}{Do.magic()} \\
And here a code block:
\begin{minted}{java}
    public class Magic(){
        public void do(){

        }
    }
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I want to get rid of writing `[fontsize=\normalsize]` everytime I use \mintinline.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but compilable code example to help us help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do even better, namely make `\mintinline` use the current font size.

The package `minted` allows for `\setmintinline`, that takes precedence over `\setminted` for `\mintinline`; the only trick is to define a macro that chooses the current font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\currentfontsize}{\fontsize{\f@size}{\f@baselineskip}\selectfont}
\makeatother

\setminted[java]{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\setmintedinline{fontsize=\currentfontsize}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE This is LARGE inline code: \mintinline{java}{Do.magic()}}

\bigskip

This is inline code: \mintinline{java}{Do.magic()}

And here a code block:
\begin{minted}{java}
    public class Magic(){
        public void do(){

        }
    }
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed the `\setmintedinline` :(

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution of @egreg works very well.
Additionally in my case it was also ok to simply put

```
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{fontsize=\scriptsize,baselinestretch=0.9, linenos}

\setmintedinline{fontsize=\normalsize}
```

and it worked also fine without first saving the font size.